# add another lookup to statement

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have this simple block of code on a form that looks up whether or not a part number exists before the order can be entered. It displays either a green check mark if it does or a red X if it doesn't. I would like to add a lookup to make sure the part number is not obsolete (true/false) as well. but I'm not sure what I need to do.

'Here is the code

```
Private Sub txtPN1_LostFocus()
If Not IsNull(txtPN1) Then
    If DCount("[PartNum]", "[PartsFinished]", "[PartNum] = '" & txtPN1 & "'") > 0 Then
        pic1.Picture = "\\TORQSERVER\Torq\Shawn\check.png"
    Else:
        pic1.Picture = "\\TORQSERVER\Torq\Shawn\cross.jpg"
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That could be:

```
If DCount("*", "[PartsFinished]", "[PartNum] = '" & txtPN1 & "' And [Obsolete] = False") > 0 Then
```